# Is there any network tab with ie8 developer tool? If not then how to track network traffic in ie8 browser?

Tags: ie-developer-tools

How can  I use IE8 Developer Tools to inspect network traffic?

Actually I  need to test if files have loaded or if any errors occurred during page load .ln Firefox/Firebug I can do this by using the NET tab.

Answer (score 9):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support network statistics in its developer tools. You'll need to upgrade to Internet Explorer 9 or use a third-party tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to inspect traffic.